# Crystal Reports - columns line displayed on the last page even there are no records

Tags: crystal-reports

I have used the following code in a formula in order to count the records:

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;
If OnLastRecord then PageofLastField := PageNumber;
```

Also, for page header, I have used the following code in a formula in order to suppress report header if there are no records:

```
Shared NumberVar PageofLastField;
PageofLastField := PageofLastField;
IF pageofLastfield <> 0 and PageNumber > PageofLastField
THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
```

But still, on the last page, the lines between columns are displayed like a dot (please see printscreen). Can anyone help me? Thanks

[image: Printscreen]

Comment: I believe you should check where the lines are really ending. Maybe they are ending inside other section (like the page header)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is not the case with your report.

[image]

this happens when you have drawn a line in header section but there is a small portion coming out to the next section. just drag the end point to the same section where the line was started in. This should solve it.